# GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES error

Tags: android

Basically i want to set geofence to more than 100 points. I tried to do that but got error 1001 that is GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES error. Is there is any way to set geofence more than 100 points in Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Geofences are limited to only 100 items. When you create the API client using the builder, the client binds your application with the package name.

For documentation visit https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes